# How to create own WebViewPage in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create own WebViewPage class so that i have created my class which is shown below

```
public abstract class iBlueWebViewPage<TModel>:WebViewPage
{
    protected iBlueWebViewPage()
    {
    }
    public HtmlHelper<TModel> iBlue { get; set; }

}
```

for example if we want text box in mvc we can code @html.TextBox("Name")
like that i need @iBlue.TextBox("Name") instead of @html
How can i achieve that ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should change base type of pages, from web configuration (**pages** element)

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, 
    System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.iBlueWebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

More detailed reading at [Phil Haack's article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx) (example is taken from there)